# Plot dash lines on plot (specifying coordinates)

Tags: pgfplots

I'd like to get the plot in the following figure (without grid):

[image]

Until now I got only axis+point:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[color=red,mark=square]coordinates{(2,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like the following?

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.11,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0,     xmax=8,
        ymin=0,     ymax=8,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        axis lines=center,
        xtick={1,2},
        ytick={1,2},
    ]
        \addplot [color=red,mark=*] coordinates {(2,2)};

        \draw [dashed,help lines] (0,2) -| (2,0);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Hello @StefanPinnow, how come it does not work if I use compat=1.9?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi, because then the TikZ coordinates have to be preceded by `axis cs:`, i.e. you have write `\draw [dashed,help lines] (axis cs:0,2) -| (axis cs:2,0);`.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi, you are welcome.